# Visual Studio 2012 C++ Debugger does not start: loading symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have solved my previous problem, that I don t have any header files by uninstall vs10 and reinstall vs12. So it compiles now and I can run the project.

But there is the next problem:
If I start my executable by running the debugger or just hitting the ("play-button") my C++ compiler compiles it and after that vs12 startes loading symbols. But I can wait for hours and  it won t do anything. It tells me that it is loading symbols for uxtheme.dll from my Debug Output folder. And it also tells me that if I cancel it will disable automatic symbol loading. But if I cancel it also just happens nothing and I have to restart visual studio 2012.

So does anyone know whats my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you set up VS to load debug symbols for system libraries from microsoft.com?
`Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols`

Comment: That just worked for me.  I was about to try reinstalling VS too!  Not sure why it suddenly became a problem overnight.